# Passing a form value to the next form element without submitting form

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-5

I have this issue where I have created a form (using Laravel), it looks like this in part:

```
{{-- Choose a category from the radios provided, this is where I need to get the $category->id and pass it to the next element for the sub category selection        
--}}

            <div class="form-group">
                <p><b>Choose a category:</b></p>

                @foreach (App\Http\Models\GalleryCategories::all() as $category)

                    {!! Form::label('category_id', $category->name) !!}
                    {!! Form::radio('category_id', $category->id, null, ['class' => 'form-field']) !!}

                @endforeach
            </div>

            {{-- Using the category id passed to this form-group I can then access only the sub categories
                 that have a gallery_categories_id = category --}}

            <div class="form-group">
                <p><b>Choose a sub category:</b></p>

                @foreach (App\Http\Models\GallerySubCategories::all() as $sub_category)

                    {!! Form::label('sub_category_id', $sub_category->name) !!}
                    {!! Form::radio('sub_category_id', $sub_category->id, null, ['class' => 'form-field']) !!}

                @endforeach
            </div>
```

The way I have the database setup is that a category has many sub categories.  So first it will display a list of categories, something like:

cat1 ( ) cat2 ( ) cat3 ( ) ...

Then the form will display the sub categories like this:

subcat1 ( ) subcat2 ( ) subcat3 ( )

But what I want to do is that when someone selects a category I want to capture that $category->id and then pass it immediately to the next form element that will then display the sub categories that relate to that category.

Easy enough if I was to break it all down and submit a couple of forms to pass the data back and forth however I wanted to be able to achieve this without the form being submitted.

It seems JS/Ajax would be the best way to accomplish this, I am not sure.  What do you think?  I have no experience yet with either however I am going to guess that it could be a fairly simple process.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you probably want it's to use jQuery and use the `.change()` event on the radio buttons that contain the categories. Then you take its value and via AJAX you send to the server the category ID and have returned via JSON their subcategories. With this JSON, you just have to loop its content, and build the new radio buttons that contain the new information. Seems a pretty easy task, there is no need at all to submit forms for this.

Comment: If you need more help I can build a js fiddle for you to see.

Comment: That would be helpful, I have looked at .change and can get it to work up to the point I get a status message returning the category_id every time I select a radio item. What I can't get my head around is being able to then take that value and pass it on to the next form element.  I guess I need some way to do a POST so that I can then get the value in PHP.

Comment: You use $.ajax() function that allows you to make POST request without fully reloading the page which is what you want in this case.

Comment: Thanks, will have a look at that.